# Bind a Text Box to a Field Selected by SQLDataSource (VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, bind, sqldatasource, textbox

I'm looking for the easiest way to bind data from a SqlDataSource to textboxes dropped in Visual Studio 2008.

For example, I have 4 textboxes currently that have Address, City, State, Zip.  I also have a SqlDataSource on the page fetching the ID of the record and selecting those 4 fields based on ID.

How am I able to quickly bind each box to those particular fields selected?  I would think this would be really straight forward - but seems it's not.  Seems like the answer is funneled towards having to create a GridView or some type of control.

Be gentle...I'm a nub :)

Comment: Do you need update support or is this read only?

Comment: I would need to eventually be able to update the value as well based on what the API return would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you are correct, if you want to use databinding you'll need to use an appropriate control. For this example I'd suggest using a FormView - it is designed to display the results from a single database record and uses templates, meaning you'll have complete control over the output. This article is probably a good place to start: [FormView Control: Step by Step](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/FormView-Control.aspx).

To read the values bound to the FormView in the code-behind class you would need to create an event handler for the FormView's `DataBound` event. In that event handler you would reference the controls programmatically via `FindControl`, like so:

```
Dim myLabel As Label = CType(FormViewID.FindControl("id"), Label)
```

Here, *id* would be the `ID` of the Label whose value you were interested in. Once you have a reference to the Label you can get its value using `myLabel.Text`.

Comment: OK - I understand this part. The 2nd part to my question would be how am I able to call the Labels or TextBoxes in the Code Behind VB? I'm relating this to an address verification API, so the user would call this page and get a selected record's address, etc.  From there I have a simple button that launches the address verification, so I believe in order to do that I would have to link the API call fields to their respective Labels or Textboxes with the record's data.

Comment: Good God.  Thanks a ton Scott, that answers my question!

Comment: @RogueSpear00: Glad to help. You might also find this control I created helpful - it's a DataBound Label. A bit easier to use than the FormView, but the downside is that it shows only one database value: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081308-1.aspx